# related products in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to display only thumbnails of products in related products area, my current code is showing the link too i.e `image` tag with href title of product name. I just want to show the thumbnails

```
<?php
    foreach($this->product->customfieldsRelatedProducts as $field) {
        echo $field->display;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think code will help you.

```
<?php
    $image_dir = JURI::root()."images/";

    foreach($this->product->customfieldsRelatedProducts as $field) {
        echo $field->display; 
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image_dir.$field->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $field->title ?>" />
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Same result,nothing happens

Comment: <?php
 foreach ($this->product->customfieldsRelatedProducts as $field) {
 $field->display = preg_replace('#(<img.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $field->display);
 ?>
    <?php echo $field->display ?>
 
 <?php } ?>